Transfer and distribution of forces in hybrid structure
It's a simple but curious question. For an object made of reinforced concrete, it is said that concrete mainly resists compression force and reinforcement mainly resists tensile force. Whether it's compressive or tensile force, it's the same in that it's an external force. I wonder why the force is distributed like that depending on the type of force.
